# Cant import variable from one script to another in python

Tags: python

I have two python script

emotion.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    user=raw_input("Enter your name\n")     

    print("Calling open smile functions.....")

    subprocess.Popen("correlationSvg.py", shell=True)
```

correlationSvg.py

```
from emotion import user
import os
import csv

with open('csv/test/'+user+'.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
  rows = list(reader)
```

i am getting error

> ImportError: cannot import name user

why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `user` is defined inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. This one is not executed when the import statement is executed.

You can of course define a (script-) global variable

```
user = ""
if __name__ == '__main__':

    user=raw_input("Enter your name\n")     

    print("Calling open smile functions.....")

    subprocess.Popen("correlationSvg.py", shell=True)
```

If you would like to get the user while execution, I would either put the line

```
user=raw_input("Enter your name\n")
```

into `correlation.py` or:

```
in  sympathy.py:

def get_user():
    user=raw_input("Enter your name\n")
```

and access this function from `correlation.py`. Just remember: the `import` statement happens at the time you call the interpreter, while user assignment happpens at runtime.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, `if` doesn't have its own scope in Python.

Comment: what if i need the value from local block ?.After doing as above am getting null value as user in correlationSvg.py

Comment: The block needs to be executed when the import happens. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `if __name__ == '__main__'`. If file is being imported from another module, `__name__` will be set to the module's name. Which means, codes in that indentation will only be processed if you run `emotion.py`.

For detailed explanation about `__name__`, you might wanna look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, to force `user` to be global:

```
user = ''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user=raw_input("Enter your name\n")
```

However... you should really think about what you are doing here. If you don't expect to set `user` unless this is the main module - what are you expecting to happen when you import it from another module?

Probably, you should be passing this as a parameter to a function, not trying to import it.

Comment: what if i need the value from local block ?.After doing as above am getting null value as user in correlationSvg.py

Comment: like others have said, `__name__` will only be `__main__` if this is the entry module, i.e. `c:\python26\python.exe emotion.py`. that's not what you want. when you import a module, _all_ its code is executed immediately (though usually, that 'code' just declares a function). If you want the user prompt to be done all the time, don't hide it behind a name check, just include it. You could also make it a function that does the user entry and returns the string; you would then just call the function.